# Allocation failed in Azure and cannot delete VMs

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I use the Microsoft Azure and I subscribed the HDInsight and its location is in Japan. A couple of days ago, I mistakenly removed all the VMs that I have been used and I determined to recover the VMs using the vhdl files. However, I changed my mind to create new VMs instead of restoring them. I successfully completed the installation of the new VMs and I installed the Hadoop and Spark and used them very well. However, a few days later, when I started my VMs, it was strangely slow to turn on and eventually it throw error indicating below message.

> Provisioning failed. Allocation failed. Please try reducing the VM
>   size or number of VMs, retry later, or try deploying to a different
>   Availability Set or different Azure location.. AllocationFailed.

I tried to follow the documents in Azure and changed the VMs size and delete the VMs that I made but deleting or changing the VMs failed throwing below message.

```
Provisioning failed. Delete/Deallocate operation on VM 'hadoop-master' failed because the remaining VMs in the Availability Set 'spark-avs' cannot be allocated together. Changes in Availability Set allocation need to be executed atomically. Please deallocate or delete some or all of these VMs before retrying the current operation. 
 Please note that this VM is not allocated and won't accrue any charges.
 Details: {
 "resourceType": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ComputeResourceProvider.Core.Strings, CRP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
 "ResourceCode": "ComputeAllocationFailure",
 "ResourceParameters": []
 }. CannotAllocateRemainingVMsInAvailabilitySet
```

Note that all the VMs that I re-installed is in the same availability set and I selected the south-korea for the new region (previous one is japan).

I tried to start many times but failed.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** When you create a VM, restart stopped (de-allocated) VMs, resize a VM, or when you add new instances, Microsoft Azure allocates compute resources to your subscription. You may occasionally receive errors when performing these operations even before you reach the [Azure subscription limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).

This article “[Troubleshoot allocation failures when you create, restart, or resize Linux VMs in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/allocation-failure)” explains the causes of some of the common allocation failures and suggests possible remediation.

If you assign Extra small, Small, and medium, you will receive validation failed error message.

**Note:** Head node recommended size is **D3 v2**, **D4 v2**, and **D12 v2**.

For more details, refer “[Default node configuration and virtual machine sizes for clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning#default-node-configuration-and-virtual-machine-sizes-for-clusters)”.

Before deploying an HDInsight cluster, plan for the desired cluster capacity by determining the needed performance and scale. This planning helps optimize both usability and costs.

Some cluster capacity decisions cannot be changed after deployment. If the performance parameters change, a cluster can be dismantled and re-created without losing stored data.

For more details, refer “[Capacity planning for HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-capacity-planning)”.